# What are the maximum number of values representable for different ranges within the floating-point representation?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

I'm trying to figure out some specifics of using a normalized representation for floating-point values.

As I understand, the IEEE-754 representation works like:

```
1.{significand} * 2^{exponent}
```

For single precision, the significand being 24 bits, the exponent being 8 bits.

What I'm trying to break this down to is essentially the number of "slots" available in each range of numbers supported by the exponent, such as:

```
[Exponent=0] 0.0 - 1.0 : 2^23 values
[Exponent=1] 1.0 - 2.0 : 2^23 values
[Exponent=2] 2.0 - 4.0 : 2^23 values
[Exponent=3] 4.0 - 8.0 : 2^23 values
```

I'm trying to demonstrate that in using quantisation if the range I'm interested in is limited to 0.0 - 1.0, I can use 2^24 bits to represent this number and there will be no loss of precision in removing the exponent and this can be easily converted to a full floating-point representation. Also, to clearly illustrate the greater precision closer to zero than further away when using floating-point, as it feels like this may be quite intuitive to understand.

One area in particular that I'm not quite clear on is where the supported exponent is -127 to 126, how does the negative portion work? 1.5 * 2^-1 clearly overlaps with the 0.0 - 1.0 range.

Finally, I know that one of the bits in the significand is used for the sign, however what does the hidden bit represent, does this affect the number of "slots" that are available in each range?

Comment: Note that the mantissa has 24 bits, but since the highest bit is always set for normalised numbers, and always cleared for de-normalised numbers, it is not stored. 23 bits of the mantissa are stored.

Comment: To answer the “use 2^24 bits to represent this number and there will be no loss of precision” part of your question, there are plenty of floating-point numbers between 0 and 0.5 that cannot be represented without loss in the 24-bit fixed-point format that you appear to be considering.

Comment: You have your exponent range a bit mixed up: *normal* numbers will have an (unbiased) exponent between -126 and 127 inclusive (corresponding to the 8 bits of the biased exponent field ranging between 1 and 254).  An exponent field of 0 is reserved for zeros and subnormals, while an exponent field of 255 is reserved for infinities and NaNs.

Comment: There aren't 2^23 values between 0.0 and 1.0:  There are 2^23 between 0.5 and 1.0, 2^23 between 0.25 and 0.5, 2^23 between 0.125 and 0.25, and so on, and so on until you get down to the denormalized numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Your table is wrong, I think. It should be:

```
....
[Exponent=-3] 0.125 - 0.25 : 223 values
[Exponent=-2] 0.25 - 0.5 : 223 values
[Exponent=-1] 0.5 - 1.0 : 223 values
[Exponent=0] 1.0 - 2.0 : 223 values
[Exponent=1] 2.0 - 4.0 : 223 values
[Exponent=2] 4.0 - 8.0 : 223 values
....
```

Or more precisely:

```
....
[Exponent=-3] 0.125 ≤ x < 0.25 : 223 values
[Exponent=-2] 0.25 ≤ x < 0.5 : 223 values
[Exponent=-1] 0.5 ≤ x < 1.0 : 223 values
[Exponent=0] 1.0 ≤ x < 2.0 : 223 values
[Exponent=1] 2.0 ≤ x < 4.0 : 223 values
[Exponent=2] 4.0 ≤ x < 8.0 : 223 values
....
```

Comment: A range of normalized floating-point numbers between 2^n inclusive and 2^(n+1) exclusive is often called “binade”. Having words for notions is useful to think, and this notion often occurs when thinking about floating-point.

Comment: Well, _you_ [often call it a binade](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Binade&action=history), that's for sure! I don't know anybody else who does, though. You are right, a word for it would be helpful, but _binade_ is such an awkward word in English.

Comment: Yeah, I am a big fan of the word. But William Kahan calls it that, too, which is good enough for me: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/testpi/nearpi.c

Comment: That source code is thirty years old! And the author is S. McDonald, not William Kahan. In any case, when you say it is 'often called "binade"', you are stretching the truth to breaking point.

Comment: I am understating it, if anything. Virtually anyone who needs to refer to this set of numbers calls it “binade”. A more recent reference is the “Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic”, published in 2010, written nine authors, each of whom is considered a reputable expert and wouldn't have let the book be published with the wrong word.

Comment: I'm quite surprised. So there are just over 8 million numbers to represent the binade with the largest negative exponent - (ie [Exponent=-126] 0 <= x < 1.2e-38) ?

Comment: You have made the same mistake again! That should be  1.175494e-38 <= x < 2.350988e-38. (0.0 is a special case.)

Comment: @TonyK: Everyone who I know who works heavily with floating-point (which is a significant sample of north-american experts on the subject) uses the term "binade"; it's not something that Pascal made up.

Comment: @StephenCanon: OK, I give in. I have worked heavily with floating point numbers myself, but not in North America. Perhaps that's why I never met the word until today.

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful. Since you're clearly the expert on this word, how do you pronounce "binade"? bye-nayde?